# Animating Chevron with Greensock

Tags: javascript, animation, sass, gsap

So I'm trying to animate a Chevron using the Greensock Library. My goal is to make [image: The downward arrow]

To into: [image: An upward facing arrow]

I have a working version on Codepen https://www.codepen.io/Brushel/pen/boryZP
I'm targeting the id of chevron and I have a little event listener attached to it using the MorphSVG gs function. However, I want to chevron to animate from the bottom point and slowly animate up. Right now It's just changing the SVG coordinates on click.

Here is the code:

```js
var chevron = document.getElementById("chevron");

chevron.addEventListener('click', function(){
  TweenLite.to("#chevron", 0.08, {
    morphSVG: "100,72.6 173.6,157.4 200,157.4 100,42.2 0,157.4 26.4,157.4"
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.st0{
  fill:#000;
}

#chevron {
  transform: scale(.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg class="mo-icon__svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="icon_x5F_chevron">
    <polygon class="st0" id="chevron" points="100,126.97715 26.4165,42.19543 0,42.19543 100,157.41371 200,42.19543 173.5835,42.19543  "/>
  </g>
  </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand your problem. check out this https://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/NaavmY

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you had a CSS transform applied which some browsers prioritize over the "transform" attribute, but the "transform" attribute is much more consistent across browsers. That's why GSAP uses it. So in your example, you had a conflict where the CSS transform was overruling the one applied in the attribute.

You should always set transform-related values directly via GSAP to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

```
TweenLite.set("#chevron", {scale:0.2});
```

Here's a revised codepen that also uses a shapeIndex to change the way the shape morphs - is that what you were looking for? 
https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/3bf8c2aec6c2171d158bdf13bff33525/